# Entering the number of elements in malloc function for a dynamic structure array in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic, malloc

At the moment, I try to understand dynamic arrays in C.
When I allocate the memory for the pointer "ptr", it is working without entering the numbers of elements (in the malloc function) I need.

Now, the problem is, don't understand why it is working.

Would be great, if someone could me some advice.
Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct daten
{
    char name[20];
    int alter;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct daten *ptr;
    int i;

    ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct daten *)); //works fine!!
    //ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct daten *)*4);
    strcpy(ptr[0].name, "Daniel");
    ptr[0].alter = 23;

    strcpy(ptr[1].name, "Fabian");
    ptr[1].alter = 29;

    strcpy(ptr[2].name, "Helmut");
    ptr[2].alter = 34;

    strcpy(ptr[3].name, "Katrin");
    ptr[3].alter = 21;

    for(i = 0; i<4; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\t", ptr[i].name);
        printf("%d\n", ptr[i].alter);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please change `sizeof(struct daten *)` -> `sizeof(struct daten)`. You want to store an object, not a pointer to an object.

Comment: @KarthikT Rather to `sizeof(*ptr)`.

Comment: @H2CO3 ah yes little bit cleaner.

Comment: @KarthikT Not that it's cleaner, but `sizeof(struct daten)` will break when `ptr` becomes anything other than `struct daten *` and you forget to change the type in the `malloc()` call.

Comment: @H2CO3 yes i meant it that way, since logic duplication is reduced, changing code is easier as you point out.

Comment: @KarthikT Ah, so you meant the same, sorry. Yes, redundancy in code is generally to be avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword is that it doesn't "work fine". At most it seems to be working.

What you have here is **undefined behavior** (since you're allocating space for one struct, however, you're writing to a much larger space). Undefined behavior can do anything; it doesn't mean the program **must crash.** This includes that it may "work fine".

Also, you're misunderstanding how much memory you should be allocating. For a type `T`, assigned to a pointer of type `T *`, `sizeof(T)` bytes should be allocated, like this:

```
ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct daten) * 4);
```

Even better:

```
ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr) * 4);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since it is an undefined behavior, anything can happen: your program may work fine. But is doesn't mean that it is a *correct* program.

Thus you *must* allocate enough memory to do this, ie `sizeof(struct daten) * 4` bytes.

Answer (score 0):

This is undefined behaviour. You are simply (un)lucky that its working. If you try this on a different system, it may or may not work.

You should do :

```
ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct daten)*4);
```

The operations are succeeding as the data is probably being written to the memory just after the allocated space. As this is unallocated space, you are not having any problems and it is `working`.  You **will** have problems when you try to use this space as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, you just write to unallocated area. This can work, but on the long run you will experience crahes, because its very likely that your heap gets corrupted by writing into unallocated areas, so successive mallocs might fail or crash your program.

Answer (score 0):

`ptr[3]` could also be expressed as `*(ptr + 3)`, where '3' is scaled to `(3 * sizeof(*p))`.  So it is copying data into some memory location way beyond the memory you have allocated.

You are lucky, or maybe I should say you are unlucky.  What you have done is a bit like randomly stabbing someone, you might hit a vital organ, or you might not.  This time you didn't, compile the code without debug (for example) to change memory layout and you might hit something that would kill the process.  Or maybe not kill it, but just injure it.

You have come across one of the reasons why programming in C has to be disciplined.  No it didn't "work", your tests were not good enough to show that it failed.

See also `calloc`.

Comment: `ptr + 3` is not the same as `ptr + (3 * sizeof(struct daten)`. Pointer arithmetic implies multiplication by `sizeof (*p)`.

Comment: Yes, I was clusily trying to say it is scaled.